# How to Extract the current date Date Log from catalina.out file

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing

I have 2.5GB catalina.out file. I need to extract the current date's logs from this file. See below my log file format:

```
2016-02-15 19:49:45 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
2016-02-15 19:49:52 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
.
.
.
2016-04-06 07:49:52 INFO XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
grep "^$(date -I)" /path/to/log
```

`date -I` will give today's date in `YYYY-MM-DD` format just like the logfile has at the start of each line.

Comment: Yes superb.Thanks for your Prompt Response.I found from my side "cat file | grep `date +%Y-%m-%d`>currnt.txt "

Comment: @GulabSherieff My one is short `date` from of yours one just without the useless `cat`..Also your one will match any anywhere in the line, not just at the start of teh line..please select my answer as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of my answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..